# Efficiency of using LINQ, USING with StreamReader and File classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

All I have is a file and a string to be searched inside it

```
Key
 Value1
 Value2
 Value3

Key1
 Value1
```

This is the structure of the file. Now, I search for a key and then read all values under it 
until I find a newline (or simply a empty line)

I use this algorithm.

```
var valuelist = new List<string>();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
  String a;
  while( (a=reader.ReadLine())!=null)
 {
  if(!a.Equals("Key")) continue;
  while( a == reader.ReadLine() != null) //check whether end of file is not reached.
  {
    if(a.Length == 0) break; //a empty line is reached.hence comeout.
    valuelist.add(a);
  }
  } 
}
```

1. I am using "using" because it automatically disposes the "reader" object ? Is my approach right in this case ?
2. How Can I use a LINQ expression here in this context ?

I tried the following code

```
var all_lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt");
 //How to retrieve "Values" for a given key using LINQ ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The use of `using` in this context is very appropriate
2. To retrieve the values for a given key, you can use [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx) looking for the key by name, followed by [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) looking for a blank line.

---

```
var list = new List<string>{
    "junk", " a", " b", "", "key", " c", " d", " e", "", "more", "f"
};
var vals = list.SkipWhile(s => s != "key").Skip(1).TakeWhile(s => s != "");
foreach (var s in vals) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: SkipWhile ? I will definitely take a look @dasblinkenlight! but, is there any code samples ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Sure, take a look. This does not read from file, but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: thanks dasblinkenlight! This use lamdba expressions right ? Anyways, I ll look in to it. Thanks again.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Right, almost anything in LINQ uses lambdas.